# When the ScrollableTabView is nested inside ScrollView, it can not show anything

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, scrollview, android-scrollable-tabs

When I use ScrollableTabView is nested inside ScrollView, it can't show anything in Android althought I updated ScrollableTabView version 0.8.0.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.3

My code like this:

```
   render() {
    return (
    <ScrollView>
      {this._renderUser()}
      <ScrollableTabView
        tabBarActiveTextColor="red"
        tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        initialPage={0}
        renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar textStyle={Styles.tabText} />}>                  
        <ScrollView
          tabLabel="线索"
          style={Styles.tabView}>
          <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow} />
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView
          tabLabel="客户档案">
          {this._renderCusProfile()}
        </ScrollView>
      </ScrollableTabView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

[Please click here to show image example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24695000/30317641-45153a30-97dd-11e7-91aa-80de94a961b0.png)

Any pointers to what I might need to change in your code to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the your style sheet. Styling used in Styles.tabView.

Comment: This is my code : 

<View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
          <ScrollView>
            {this.renderCheckoutModal()}
            {this.renderPhotosView()}
            {this.renderInfoView()}
            {/* {this.renderDescView()} */}
            {this.renderDoctorsTitle()}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

Answer (score 1):

import Dimensions from react native :

```
import {
  ...
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
```

then you bring height :

```
const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

And you apply hight to ScrollableTabView

```
  <ScrollableTabView
        style={{ height: height, position: 'relative' }}
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what styling includes in your Styles.tabView.
If you use { flex: 1 } inside your style object for  this might work.

Comment: I removed style in ScrollView. Now I don't use anymore style for ScrollView

Comment: My project have :

<ScrollView>

  {this._renderUser}

  <ScrollableTableView

     ...... >

       data

  </ScrollableTabView>

</ScrolLView>